# jQuery select : get different var using $(.class)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the ddslick library to generate my select.
I use the selects as generic filters.
I also use a lot of `$.dialog` to get a desktop aspect on my application.

So the idea is I want my select to appear on each dialogs windows, using a class like that:

```
$(".filters").ddslick(random instructions)
```

Each DIV labelled with the class "filters" then receive and draw a ddslick very well, no matter if it's 5 windows at the same time.

It works very well, the selects are even independent until i open 2 dialog windows at the same time!

Then, if i choose something in the first windows, it also choose the same thing in the second window.  That means that the variables aren't related or unique to only one window!

This is a big problem, because it can lead to big errors.

I need the ddslick to return the chosen variable to only one window.

This is a picture to make you understand:

http://hpics.li/807223b

This is my code :

```
    // download and populate ddslick values
    $.ajax({
        url: 'creerSelect.php',  
        type: 'GET',
        data: $.param({'table':'categcours'}),
        success: function (data) {
                data=eval(data);
                afficheSelect(data);
                }
    }); 

    function afficheSelect(data){ // make ddslick selects appear on each div labelled filters
        $(".filtres").ddslick({
            data: data,
            width: 150,
            imagePosition: "left",
            selectText: titre,  
            onSelected: function (data) {
                window.choix    = data.selectedIndex+1;// get the selected variable on the global scope : how to use it after and make it unique and closed to only one jquery dialog ?

                }
        }); 

    }
```

I've tried `this.choix`, but it doesn't relate to the dialog window. I think I should create an object for each windows maybe? I really haven't got any idea about how to do this. It's really complex to link a filter that had been generated by a class with jQuery, to a unique dialog window !

Comment: Not sure about what I'm saying here, but try `$(".filtres").each( function(){ $(this).ddslick(.....) })` I hope that, by doing so, it will wrap each one in its own function (that is, a closure) and may isolate the scopes...

Comment: Thank you a lot ! Let's try this, I will let you know thank you:! Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the code, and it works well, but does the same thing. I still don't know how to relate a generic select to a particular div.

I open a window, the select-filter works well, but if i open another window, select another filter, and go back to the first windows,  obtain the value of the second windows into the first window, that leads to an error.

I thinking about creating a javascript object maybe for each jquery window-div-dialog

My goal is that i dont want to re-write the generic select-filters for each windows-div-dialog.

It's really difficult.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'creerSelect.php',  // populate the select filter
        type: 'GET',
        data: $.param({'table':'categcours'}), // select an sql table
        success: function (data) {
                data=eval(data);


                $(".filtres").each( function(){ 

                    $(this).ddslick({ // each div labelled with the .filtres class will show the generic select filters
                        data: data,
                        width: 150,
                        imagePosition: "left",
                        selectText: titre,  
                        onSelected: function (data) {
                            this.choix  = data.selectedIndex+1;// How to link the selected variable to a particular div-dialog-window ? It's really hard ! Reminds me of a "private" thing ? Maybe i have to use "return" something ?

                        }
                    }); 
                })
        }
```

});

Comment: HO i 've got another idea, maybe i should disable the other windows div filters while the user works into one windows.

Comment: For now, i 'm forced to re-write a unique ddslick filter function for each windows, its not short but it will work. Thank you a lot for your tip, it will help in the future.

Comment: Another idea : I should reinit the whole filters while clicking on a particular jquerydialog on click.